# Should a new fragment started from a fragment in a View Pager be loaded to a new activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I would like to create a good base for my app and have it working efficiently. I am a bit lost still with understanding the relationships between fragments and activities (in the basic form I get it, but in cases like the one I need to deal with now I am not sure what to do).

Currently I have 3 fragments in a View Pager, very simple stuff. one of them is for gallery, one of them is for profile and one of them is for forum (imagine the question board here on SO).

Now, inside the forum fragment I have a FAB that should open a new page for asking a new question.

1. What I am wondering about is, should the new question page be a fragment or an activity? Also, when a question is clicked I would like its thread to open with all the comments. That should be a fragment as well correct?
2. If fragment, where do I load it into? The View Pager? If so how? Can the view pager host a fragment temporarily? Because the fragment should only be visible when the button has been clicked. Should I place the fragments inside of the forum fragment so it'll serve as it's parent fragment?

I can make it as an activity, but by what I read and know about fragments, it makes sense that it should be a fragment because it is part of the same activity, but when that is that case I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would actually not use a ViewPager in your case.  I use ViewPagers for a series of related screens that deal with a very specific task.  For example - a wizard that details instructions where each Fragment might represent a step and it's useful for the user to be able to slide back and forth between instructions.

Given your requirements I would still host everything under one Activity and the individual pages as Fragments inside that activity.  Then maybe use something like a bottom nav bar to navigate between the profile, gallery and forum.  The screen that is launched by the FAB and another one for viewing the thread of a forum post should be also be separate Fragments as well.

This might be a good opportunity for you to try out the navigation framework under Jetpack.  It makes these kinds of things a lot easier to visualize.

See here [Android Navigation Framework](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation)

Comment: Thank you answering. I'll read the documentation you've attached.
I didn't expect the answer to suggest not using the view pager so I don't mention that the reason I went for a view pager was because I wanted to have a camera activity/fragment when sliding to the left (like instagram), but not have its icon in the bottom navigation bar.
I don't mind only having the main screen and the camera on the view pager and the rest work with the bottom nav, but them I am facing the same question, where should the fragments load into in that main screen, if it is already populated by the adapter?

Comment: I see that clears it up some.    If you're not going for a ViewPager then you're not going to be using a ViewPagerAdapter.  You'll be instantiating Fragments and managing them yourself using fragment transaction manager.  Or if you're using the navigation framework, it can handle that for you and you just define the transitions.  That said you have a valid reason to use a ViewPager and in your case, I would actually do the entire forum/comment/comment thread functionality as a separate Activity task instead with it's own Fragments.

Comment: Thank you! I've been reading the documentation you've attached and it simplifies things so much. I'm new to Android development so wasn't aware of it. I'm sure that once I'm done things would much clearer, thank you.